# Object create define property setter

Tags: javascript, oop, setter, defineproperty

I need to make it so that every time a specific property on my object is changed - it will call a special method on the same object.

Example:

```
MyObject.prototype = Object.create({
    specialMethod: function() { /* ... */ }
  }, {
    someValue: {
      set: function(value) {

        /* HOW DO I ASSIGN THE VALUE TO MyObject HERE?*/
        /* I can't do: this.someValue=value, that would create endless recursion */

        this.specialMethod();
      }
    }
  });
```

How do I assign the value to MyObject within the property setter?

Comment: Assigning `MyObject` would ruin all that. You could theoretically do `MyObject = value`, but as i said, that destroys the prototype.

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite `MyObject`?

Comment: I assume you simply want to assign a property of the current `MyObject` instance? Just use `this` as always.

Comment: @Bergi, I can't that would create an endless recursion, cause assigning `this.someValue` calls the setter

Comment: @YemSalat: You didn't tell us *which* property you wanted to assign to. `this.MyValue = value` would work flawlessly…

Comment: I think he means *this.someValue* = value

Comment: I want to assign to the value that I'm creating a setter for. In this example `someValue`. No, I can't assign to it within the constructor via `this.someValue = value`, as I explained above that would keep calling the setter forever.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: Object.observe doesn't fit what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Hrishi: `Object.observe`?

Comment: It's new in JavaScript Harmony http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe

Comment: @Hrishi: That's a proposal. I don't see that it has been accepted.

Comment: @Hirshi, decided to stick with ES5 for this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no storage place in a getter/setter property, you cannot store values on it. You need to store it somewhere else and create a getter for that. Two solutions:

1. Use a second, "hidden" property:

   ```
   MyObject.prototype.specialMethod: function() { /* ... */ };
   Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, "someValue", {
       set: function(value) {
           this._someValue = value;
           this.specialMethod();
       },
       get: function() {
           return this._someValue;
       }
   });
   ```
2. Use a closure variable (typically created on construction of the
   instance):

   ```
   function MyObject() {
       var value;
       Object.defineProperty(this, "someValue", {
           set: function(v) {
               value = v;
               this.specialMethod();
           },
           get: function() {
               return value;
           }
       });
   }
   MyObject.prototype.specialMethod: function() { /* ... */ };
   ```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Sorry about the confusion with initial example. This is exactly what I needed (decided to go with the closure so the object wont be littered with 'hidden' properties)